# Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder could not be converted to string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm making function in controller where I want to attach user and his orders. First I'm making relationship between two models `User` and `Orders`.

This is function in `User` model:

```
public function orders(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Orders', 'user_orders', 'user_id', 'order_id');

    }
```

This is function in `Orders` model:

```
public function users(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_orders', 'order_id', 'user_id');
   }
```

This is the new table `user_orders` where I want to attach the user orders with this relationship that I mentioned:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUserOrdersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
       Schema::create('user_orders', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->increments('id');

            /*$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

            $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders');*/

            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('order_id');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('user_orders');
    }
}
```

And in the end this is the function where I'm getting the username with request and order id and try to attach the orders to the given user.

```
public function makeOrder(Request $request, $id){

        $user = User::where('name', $request['username'])->first();

        $findorder = Orders::find($id);


        $user->orders()->detach();
        $user->orders()->attach(Orders::where('id', $findorder))->first();


        return redirect()->back();

    }
```

I have check also if I'm getting the right user name and order id and the first two lines of the code worked perfect, but when i try to attach the orders I'm getting this error:

```
ErrorException in Str.php line 289:
Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder could not be converted to string
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get first object and then get an ID:

```
$user->orders()->attach(Orders::where('id', $findorder)->first()->id);
```

You should pass an ID to [`attach()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships) method, but not a collection or an object.

**UPDATE**

It seems that `$findorder` is an order ID, so just do this:

```
$user->orders()->attach($findorder);
```

Comment: If i run this code I have this error: `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: That's because `first()` returns `null`. Make sure the record exists.

Comment: @epowah, this means you do not have `Order` with ID = `$findorder`.

Comment: If `$findorder` is an ID of real order which is in `orders` table, just do this: `$user->orders()->attach($findorder);`

Comment: Yes it works now! Thank you so much, but again i didn't get it why this code don't work `$user->orders()->attach(Orders::where('id', $findorder)->first()->id);`

Comment: Also another question, the database is saving the last order, if i have two orders for example I have only the last clicked order..

Comment: @epowah, if you're asking about how to attach two orders, you can pass an array of IDs `attach([$firstOrder, $secondOrder])`

Comment: It is because of detach function(), maybe i should delete this function and check if the clicked orded is ordered before I show some alert

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127181/discussion-between-epowah-and-alexey-mezenin).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fairly simple. Namely this line:

`$user->orders()->attach(Orders::where('id', $findorder))->first();`

and more specifically:

`Orders::where('id', $findorder)`

As it stands this will return a `Model` object, which does not have(nor should it) implemeted the `__toString` method.

Long story short, after `Orders::where('id', $findorder)` add `->first()` or whatever it is you need to get.

---

See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) for more details on attaching/detaching.

Comment: I didn't understand you at all, actually thats the same code that i write..

Comment: It's not. Read it carefully. You have `->first()` AFTER `Orders::where('id', $findorder)`, what I'm saying is have `Orders::where('id', $findorder)->first()`. So your code will look like: `$user->orders()->attach(Orders::where('id', $findorder)->first())->first();`. Notice that there are 2 `first()` not 1.

Comment: Ahaa i get it now, i change this line and now i have another error: `Call to a member function first() on null`

Comment: In that case `Orders::where('id', $findorder)` is not returning any records. `first()` will return null in case of failure, unlike `->get()` which will return an empty collection. An inconsistency which I find mildly annoying. Make sure that the record exists.

Comment: @epowah, you should use an ID instead of object as `attach()` parameter.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Is correct. I completely forgot about the id. His answer is more suitable.

Comment: I think that now I see the mistake, how should look that line of code?

Comment: Well, firstly check that whatever you're attaching exists. If it doesn't don't attach it. So something along the lines of `$order = Orders::where('id', $findorder);  if(!is_null($order)){ //do stuff here} `